# Default dynamic dispatcher of Vulkan-Hpp can't load function correctly

Tags: c++, vulkan

I'm trying to migrate my old vulkan code with C binding to C++ binding. However, it seems that the function pointer inside default dynamic dispatcher `VULKAN_HPP_DEFAULT_DISPATCHER` will change after initialized.

The code related to the dispatcher initialization is grabbed from the documentation of [Vulkan-Hpp](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Hpp#extensions--per-device-function-pointers):

```cpp
vk::DynamicLoader dyna_loader;
auto vkGetInstanceProcAddr =
    dyna_loader.getProcAddress<PFN_vkGetInstanceProcAddr>(
            "vkGetInstanceProcAddr");
VULKAN_HPP_DEFAULT_DISPATCHER.init(vkGetInstanceProcAddr);
// creating instance...
VULKAN_HPP_DEFAULT_DISPATCHER.init(m_instance);
// creating device...
VULKAN_HPP_DEFAULT_DISPATCHER.init(m_device);
```

The codes above can run correctly. However, when I try to destroy the device, an accession violation exception would be thrown (I'm in Windows) in the following code snippet:

```cpp
// part of vulkan.hpp
  template <typename Dispatch>
  VULKAN_HPP_INLINE void Device::destroy( Optional<const VULKAN_HPP_NAMESPACE::AllocationCallbacks> allocator, Dispatch const & d ) const VULKAN_HPP_NOEXCEPT
  {
    VULKAN_HPP_ASSERT( d.getVkHeaderVersion() == VK_HEADER_VERSION );

    d.vkDestroyDevice( m_device,
                       reinterpret_cast<const VkAllocationCallbacks *>( static_cast<const VULKAN_HPP_NAMESPACE::AllocationCallbacks *>( allocator ) ) );
  }
```

The program tried to execute through the function pointer `vkDestroyDevice` and throw the exception:

```
Exception has occurred: W32/0xC0000005
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF8FCF2BFB6 (vulkan-1.dll) in RayTracing.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000008.
```

And I checked the `vkDestroyDevice` pointer inside default dispatcher, which is `vulkan-1.dll!0x00007ff8fcefc6a0`

I tried to initialize the dispatcher again in the cleanup code, it didn't work though:

```cpp
vk::DynamicLoader dyna_loader;
auto vkGetInstanceProcAddr =
    dyna_loader.getProcAddress<PFN_vkGetInstanceProcAddr>(
        "vkGetInstanceProcAddr");
VULKAN_HPP_DEFAULT_DISPATCHER.init(vkGetInstanceProcAddr);
VULKAN_HPP_DEFAULT_DISPATCHER.init(m_instance);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After went through the vulkan.hpp header, I found that the `vk::DynamicLoader dyna_loader` actually holds a handle pointing to the DLL. So when the local variable goes out of the scope, the DLL is unloaded. So just store the dynamic loader as part of the class or somewhere else you'd be fine.